# Searching string with specific conditions

Tags: regex

i am searching for a regex for a string containing 'a' and 'b' that has the following two attributes:
1: The String has an Even number of characters
2: The String may not contain 'aa'

Comment: It is hardly possible to do that with one regex.

Comment: You should be able to do that with 3 regular expressions. One for each condition :P

Comment: Does the string contain only `a` and `b` or `abcd` is a valid string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily done with Perl-compatible regular expressions:
`^(ab|bb|(ba(?!a)))*$`

Basically it says that string must consist of `ab`, `bb`, `ba` substrings mixed in any order, BUT `ba` cannot follow another `a` character.

The string will have even length because all these subexpressions have even length. `aa` can't appear in a string, because the only way for it to appear is in substring `baab`, but the regex specifically restricts ba to be followed by `a`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with standard (old) regex:

`(ab|bb|(ba)*bb)*(ba)*`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/(?=^(?:..)+$)(?!aa)(?=.*a)(?=.*b)/
```

**explanation:**

```
/         : delimiter
          : control there are an even number of char
  (?=     : positive lookahead
    ^     : begining of string
    (?:   : non capture group
      ..  : 2 characters
    )+    : one or more times
    $     : end of string
  )
          : control there aren't aa
  (?!     : negative look ahead
    aa    : aa
  )
          : control there is at least an a
  (?=     : positive lookahead
    .*a   : at least an a
  )
          : control there is at least a b
  (?=     : positive lookahead
    .*b   : at least a b
  )
/         : delimiter
```